# Is the App service plan created for a Consumption based Azure Function reusable?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

When creating an Azure Function with Consumption based pricing an App Service Plan is created. Can I bind additional Functions to this cart and will this cause some side effects?

Comment: What do you mean by bind additional functions? You mean additional Function Apps to the same App Services Plan?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can connect multiple [Azure Function Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) to the same App Service Plan regardless of whether it's a consumption plan or fixed ("Premium") plan.

Plan pricing is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) for Azure Function apps. It's available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) for all Azure App Services. Consumption plan Azure Function Apps should not be bound to the same App Service Plan as other [Azure App Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/). I think the Azure Portal prohibits you from even doing this, without well-explained error messages.

In my personal experience, I have 3 Azure Function Apps bound to the same App Service plan without any issues or side effects. I also have several App Services created tied to a different non-consumption App Service Plan.